# Can the maybe_unused attribute specifier appear only once and still work?

Tags: c++, c++17

I like the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute and use it a lot when I need to compile out debug-only function implementations. I am a little confused where it should be used when specifying member function arguments as `[[maybe_unused]]`.

Given:

```cpp
//Foo.h
class Foo {
    void DebugOnly(Bar& fly);
}

//Foo.cpp
void Foo::DebugOnly(Bar& fly) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    fly.squish();
#endif
}
```

Does specifying it in both places make a difference?

```cpp
//Foo.h
class Foo {
    void DebugOnly([[maybe_unused]] Bar& fly);
}

//Foo.cpp
void Foo::DebugOnly([[maybe_unused]] Bar& fly) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    fly.squish();
#endif
}
```

Or should I only declare it in the header or implementation file?

Header-only

```cpp
//Foo.h
class Foo {
    void DebugOnly([[maybe_unused]] Bar& fly);
}

//Foo.cpp
void Foo::DebugOnly(Bar& fly) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    fly.squish();
#endif
}
```

Implementation-file-only

```cpp
//Foo.h
class Foo {
    void DebugOnly(Bar& fly);
}

//Foo.cpp
void Foo::DebugOnly([[maybe_unused]] Bar& fly) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    fly.squish();
#endif
}
```

The page on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) does not make a distinction for function arguments and only classifies them as "variables".

Comment: It has meaning only in the implementation declaration. Adding it to the declaration is most likely pointless.

Comment: @ALX23z That's called **definition**.